# Understanding C++ function with return type void *

Tags: c++, void-pointers, unreal-engine5

I am working in Unreal Engine C++ and wish to fetch the vertex normals of a static mesh. To do this I am using the `GetTangentData()` method which belongs to the `FStaticMeshVertexBuffer` class ([link](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Rendering/FStaticMeshVertexBuffer/)).

The `GetTangentData()` method is defined two ways in the docs ([link1](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Rendering/FStaticMeshVertexBuffer/GetTangentData/1/), [link2](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Rendering/FStaticMeshVertexBuffer/GetTangentData/2/)):

`void * GetTangentData()`

`const void * GetTangentData() const`

My understanding is that this is a getter function. However, I am unsure why it has a void pointer return type. The following line compiles but I am unsure how to access the data:

`void* TangentData = StaticMeshVertexBuffer->GetTangentData();`

**Q1**. What is the reason to have a void pointer return type?

**Q2**. How can one access the data from such a return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1.** What is the reason to have a void pointer return type?

A `void*` is a pointer to something, but that something is not known. Thus, there is a degree of flexibility to `void*`, resulting in the ability to be cast into many types of pointers. For example, `malloc` has a return type of `void*` because it's supposed to be used to allocate memory for all types of pointers. In C++, we can code function overloads because templates exist, so `void*` is more of a C thing. It is used in C++ to maintain backwards compatibility with C for libraries that are designed for usage with both C++ and C.

**Q2.** How can one access the data from such a return?

You typecast it:

```
void* void_ptr = func_that_returns_void_ptr();
char* char_ptr_typecast = (char*) void_ptr;
std::cout << char_ptr_typecast << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and thoughtful answers to both questions. Much appreciated!